# Hibernate Criteria One to Many

Tags: hibernate, orm, hql, criteria

I have this sentence:

```
List l=getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(
    "from Domain d where d.location.idLocation=?").
     setParameter(0, idLocation).list();
```

and I need this query but using Criteria, but I don't know how to use Criteria in a Relation
1 to many.

Thx

Comment: Resolve: Criteria criteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Domain.class);
    criteria.createCriteria("location").add(Restrictions.eq("idLocation", idLocation)).list();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
 Criteria criteria = getDatabaseSession().createCriteria(Domain.class); 
 criteria.createAlias("location","loc");
 criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("loc.idLocation", idLocation));
 List<Domain> l=(List<Domain>)criteria.list();
```